# My fun conjecture about linearly independence

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

In the $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector space, there are distinct $m$ vectors $v_i$'s ($1< i\leq m)$
such that each component has value 0 or 1.

Let $A_i$ be the set of $j$'s where $j$-th component of $v_i$ is 1.

Also, for each $i \neq j$, $A_i$ and $A_j$ has common $k$ elements. Where $k$ is a given integer $1\leq k <n$.

For example, when $n=3, k=1$. $v_1=(1,1,0), v_2=(1,0,1), v_3=(0,1,1)$ satisfy those conditions since $A_1=\{1,2\},A_2=\{1,3\},A_3=\{2,3\}$.

My conjecture is : those $v_i$'s are linearly independent.

With some rough programming, this conjecture was true when $n \leq 10$.

I tried to prove this conjecture with induction on $k$, but I failed.

*Some people misunderstood question.

Actually question is : For given $n,m,k$, is every families of vectors with above condition are linearly independent.

Can you prove or disprove this conjectrue?

Comment: $(1,0), (0,1), (1,1)$ are linearly dependent but seem to satisfy your description.

Comment: @lhf (1,0) and (0,1) has no common elements but other pair has 1 common elements

Comment: As I have understood it, your conjecture says that given $k$, if a subset $V$ of $B=\{$ vectors whose components are 0 or 1$\}$ satisfies the property of that for each pair of vectors in $V$, the number of 1-components that have in common is $k$, then $V$ is l.i. Is it correct?

Comment: Hmm, so if there is some $j$ for which precisely one of the vectors has a $1$ in the $j$'th position, then one can safely remove that and proceed by induction on $m$. I am not sure if this leads anywhere though.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Your claim doesn't work. See example on my question.

Comment: What do you mean my claim does not work? That example does not satisfy what I needed in my claim.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I meant your claim can't prove all cases in that way.

Comment: Right, I know that. But it might be able to put some further restrictions on which $k$ or $m$ are possible (it seems that if we require at least two vectors with a $1$ for each entry, then there need to be enough vectors or not too many entries in common).

Comment: You have to restrict $k > 0$. Otherwise, $0$ and $1$ satisfy the description, but are trivially dependent. Also, you need $m > 1$ because any single-element set trivially satisfies the conditions, but a set containing only $0$ is not linearly independent.

Comment: @VedranŠego, I forget that trivial expection thanks. I'll fix it

Comment: @VedranŠego Sure, I was hoping to put further restrictions on the numbers using my argument (no idea if it is actually possible). Another degenerate case that should be ruled out is that we need the vectors to be distinct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your condition says that $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle = k$ when $i\ne j$, and let's write $\langle v_i,v_i\rangle = n_i$. Let $A$ be the matrix having the $v_i$ as columns. Then

$$A^TA = \begin{pmatrix}n_1 & k & k & \cdots & k \\
                          k & n_2 & k & \cdots & k \\
                            &  & \ddots & & \\
                          k & k & k & \cdots & n_m
\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that at most one of the $n_i$ can be equal to $k$ because any two of them would have to be equal. Also note that we have to explicitly exclude the case that $v_i = 0$ for some $i$. Otherwise we are done: $A^TA$ is clearly invertible so $A$ can not have a non-trivial kernel, i.e. no non-trivial linear combination of its columns, the $v_i$, can give $0$.